# Naming an array using a textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uitextfield

In my app people save the value of textfields into an array which they can then load up the by selecting a row in a UITableView. The row they click on corresponds to an array of values. They can name each array of values (and therefore the row in the table view) using a textfield in a different view. However, I don't know how to set the name of an array to equal a textfield and how I make that load up into a table view. Each array will contain all the textfields values (integer values) but they will want to put different sets of values in the texfields at different times and then load up an array (containing the set of textfield values) by clicking on a row in the tableview with the name from the textfield in the other view which they used to name the array (that textfield won't be part of the array but it will be what's displayed in the table view to load up the array of textfields corresponding to that name).

Comment: Just...why? I would consider it bad design for the user to chose the name of YOUR variables...

Comment: This is an exact repeat of your previous question. It was closed for a reason. Duplicating it again does not change that reason. Improve your question so you have a better chance of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your goal correctly, I'd probably make an `NSDictionary` with keys for each of the textfields, and then have an array stored as the value for each of those keys.  So you'd have "John" as the key for [34,83,29] and then "David" as the key for [41,65,67] and so on.  That way you could set and get the arrays based on the textfield values.

It's kind of a counter-intuitive design, though, to be honest.  But if you want to associate a set of arrays with user-set strings, that's probably where I'd start.

If that doesn't help (or if I'm misunderstanding your question), try providing some more information and code for what you already have, and what you'd tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would design this, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Is create custom classes subclassing UITableViewCell, and these cells contain a array of your data. and also contain the value of your text field.

I'm having difficulty understanding the second half of your paragraph there though.